# Span and img tags as vertical center for div

Tags: html, css

I have div tag, in him is span and img tags, I want that span and img will be as vertical center for div, I am truing this but for span tag `margin-top` not works and I can not centering span tag. What is solution?

```
<div>
    <span>
        some text
    </span>
    <img  src="..." />
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    width: 200px; 
    height: 40px; 
    background: #ccc   
}

span {
    margin-top: -10px; 
}

img {
   width:20px;
    height: 20px;   
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

this is demo http://jsfiddle.net/Q9utY/4/

Comment: Um, what? I'm not quite sure what you mean by "vertical center for div"?

Comment: that is `vertical align: middle` for parent div tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with padding

```
div {
   width: 200px; 
   padding: 20px;
   background: #ccc   
}


img {
   width:20px;
   height: 20px;   
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/isijop/1/

and here we can use line-height with height

```
div {
   width: 200px; 
   height: 40px;
   line-height: 40px;
   background: #ccc   
}

img {
   width:20px;
   height: 20px;   
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/apawog/1/

Comment: Sorry Ahmad for posting a similar solution, i was typing when you submitted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Span is by default inline element, so margin doesn't affect it.

to fix this, add `display:block` or `display:inline-block` to span.

But personally I don't think this is the best way to do it. Here is some article with 6 ways of doing it.

[6 Methods For Vertical Centering With CSS](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/)

Answer (score 0):

Add vertical-align:middle for img class.

```
vertical-align:middle;
```

Try here

http://jsfiddle.net/Q9utY/4/